# Basic example of using HaskellDB to unmap records of a table

Tags: haskell, haskelldb

Suppose that I have the following (PostgreSQL) table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE books (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    title character varying NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And the following record definition:

```
data Book = 
  { id :: Int
  , title :: String
  }
```

What is a basic example of an "unmap" function to query all books in the database, `allBooks :: Database -> IO [Book]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that I was going about this the wrong way.

After stumbling upon [Mats Rauhala](https://github.com/MasseR)'s exceedingly helpful blog post titled [Example on using HaskellDB](http://users.utu.fi/machra/posts/2011-07-15-haskelldb.html), I was able to write a test project to read the records of the `books` table.

I first needed to define the "layout", which, using haskelldb-th, is not too bad:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Tables.Books (
    books
  , id
  , title
  , Books
  ) where

import Database.HaskellDB.CodeGen
import Prelude hiding (id)

mkDBDirectTable "Books" [
    ("id", [t|Int|])
  , ("title", [t|String|])
  ]
```

From there, the `allBooks` function is:

```
allBooks db = query db $ do
    books <- table B.books
    return books
```

where `B` is the qualified name of imported module `Tables.Books`. `allBooks` has the type:

```
allBooks :: Database
            -> IO
                 [Record
                    (Database.HaskellDB.HDBRec.RecCons
                       Tables.Books.Id
                       Int
                       (Database.HaskellDB.HDBRec.RecCons
                          Tables.Books.Title
                          String
                          Database.HaskellDB.HDBRec.RecNil))]
```

To print out each title, I used:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    books <- postgresqlConnect [("host", "localhost"), ("user", "test"), ("password", "********")] allBooks
    mapM_ putStrLn (map (\r -> r!B.title) books)
    return ()
```

**EDIT:** I created a git repository containing the complete sources of this example: [dtrebbien/haskelldb-example](https://github.com/dtrebbien/haskelldb-example)