# Does Haskell have a SQL query-composing library like ActiveRecord or Sequel?

Tags: haskell, hdbc

With Ruby's ActiveRecord or [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/), you can progressively build up SQL queries, adding `where` or `join` or `order` clauses to a query depending on conditions at run time.

Here is a simple example, taken from [ASCIIcasts](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3):

```
def index  
  @articles = Article.order('name')  

  if params[:hidden]  
    @articles = @articles.where(:hidden =>(params[:hidden] == "1"))  
  end  

  respond_to do |format|  
    format.html # index.html.erb  
    format.xml  { render :xml => @articles }  
  end  
end
```

The example shows how a WHERE clause can be appended to the underlying SQL query on the `articles` table if an HTTP request query parameter named `hidden` equals `1`.

I've been looking at HDBC and postgresql-simple in Haskell. It seems that postgresql-simple purposely makes it difficult to build up SQL queries from dynamically concatenated parts, in order to prevent SQL injection. HDBC does seem to be flexible enough to build up differently structured SQL queries based on conditions at runtime, but it doesn't seem to provide the level of abstraction that either ActiveRecord or Sequel provide.

Can anyone suggest a nice way to emulate ActiveRecord's dynamic query-building facilities using one of the Haskell database libraries?

If HDBC is the way to go, I'm fine with that. But an illustration would be appreciated.

I guess what I am lookinng for is the ability to dynamically compose queries, against a PostgreSQL backend.

Comment: It sounds like you want haskelldb instead.  Sorry, I'm not familiar with it.  It does have a PostgreSQL back-end, though.

Comment: This might help: [Basic example of using HaskellDB to unmap records of a table](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7697620/196844)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want [Persistent](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent), you may want [HaskellDB](http://chrisdone.com/posts/2011-11-06-haskelldb-tutorial.html), you may want something like Esqueleto.

Here's a good discussion of the tradeoffs of each:
http://blog.felipe.lessa.nom.br/?p=68

Answer (score 5):

You may find http://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto interesting for this application.